# PHP download prompt script downloads to server as well

Tags: php, download, wysiwyg, php-ziparchive, webclient

I wrote a PHP script that creates a zipfile and prompts the browser for download. Not only does it download to the client, for some reason it also creates a duplicate zipfile in my server in the same directory as this script.

I only want this script to download to the client, and not a duplicate on my server.

```
$layoutName  = $_POST['layoutName'];
$htmlContent = $_POST['htmlContent'];

$layoutDir = 'http://myapp.com/public/views/layouts/' . $layoutName;

$zipFileName = 'Myapp-' . $layoutName . '.zip';
$decompressedFolderName = 'Myapp-' . $layoutName;

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);

if($zip)
{
    // Add index.html
    $zip->addFromString('index.html', $htmlContent);

    // Add CSS Folder
    $cssContent = file_get_contents($layoutDir . '/css/default.css', false);
    $zip->addFromString('css/default.css', $cssContent);

} else {
    echo 'Could not create zip';
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/octet-type');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Myapp-' . $layoutName . '.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFileName)); 

ob_clean();
flush();

echo file_get_contents($zipFileName);

exit;
```

**UPDATE**
PROBLEM SOLVED. This code now works!

Comment: You're specifically creating $zipFileName on the server before downloading it to the client, so delete it from the server once the readfile() has completed

Comment: Thank you. That was my exact problem. I changed readfile() to file_get_contents(), and not it doesn't create the file on my server. Every example that I found used readfile(). Thank you again.

Comment: @Rashad Please Mark question is fixed by answering yourself or changing question status.

Comment: @JensonMJohn What do you mean by "changing question status"?

Comment: @vascowhite From status Open to Close

Comment: @JensonMJohn [Closing a question is done by the community](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). A user cannot unilaterally close their own question, only vote to do so.

Comment: @vascowhite Alright..:)

Answer (score 1):

That was my exact problem. I changed readfile() to file_get_contents(), and now it doesn't create the file on my server.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before it allows me to.